# In VS, is there a way to ignore errors on some typescript files but still compile them in?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I'm writing a large application with several 3rd party libraries. Right now, I am using a post-build script to concatenate all of my .js files together, along with the output of all my combined typescript files. This works fine, but makes it so the source mappings are off for debugging.

What I'd like to accomplish is converting all of my 3rd party .js libraries into typescript (and by converting, I mean just renaming them from .js to .ts since typescript is a superset). From here, I can just use the typescript compiler to output all of the combined typescript files with accurate source maps so debugging in typescript will still work. However, the issue I'm running into is that the 3rd party libraries have various errors, so I cannot get the build to work.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to have my existing typescript files compiled as they are while having these third party libraries compiled but ignoring all errors and have the result all output into one single javascript file?

Comment: Update: I don't think there is an easy way to do this. We ended up using a lot of Sohnee's suggestions and actually modified our build script to just use a debug configuration that would load in two separate files for debug mode and then combines them for a production build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is able to forgive a whole host of errors and still provide compiled JavaScript, but in some cases the error will prevent it - i.e. the code will no longer make sense to the compiler because it cannot determine enough information.

The solution would be to splatter lots of `: any` type annotations to suppress errors.

The real danger with your approach will be trying to keep your edited versions of all of the libraries updated as they change.

Here is an alternative...

Combine all of your third party libraries into a single file, then combine all of your TypeScript files into a single file (so your source maps work).

This will allow you to easily debug and you could always crush the two files together later if the extra HTTP request worries you.

Comment: I don't think the : any solution will work for us because we are trying to dynamically update our 3rd parties via nuget. We are really hoping to get them all into one single file because we plan on minifying everything later, and if we minify two separate files there might be name collisions. Sounds like I might just have to stick to combining all of the .js files post-build and lose the source-mappings.

Comment: Yes - the `any` solution clashes with keeping updated (as per the third paragraph above) - that's why I don't recommend the approach. You can either lose the source mappings, or have a multi-stage process (two files in debug, combined into one file and then minified otherwise).